# Find the remaining vector when a vector and crossproduct is known

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

"Let $ v_1= \left(\begin{matrix}\frac{-2\sqrt(13)}{13}\\0\\\frac{-3\sqrt(13)}{13}\end{matrix}\right) $  and $ v_2= \left(\begin{matrix}0\\1\\0\end{matrix}\right) $ be two orthonormal vectors.

Following crossproduct is given: $v_1 \times v_3 =v_2$.

Determine $v_3$."

I don't quite get how you are supposed to solve this, and it doesn't make it easier that $v_1$ has such weird coordinates. Can anyone see how you are supposed to do?

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions.  If we want $v_3$ to be orthogonal to $v_1$ and $v_2$ though, then there is a unique solution and a neat trick to finding this solution.

Comment: The problem doesn't specify anything about $v_3$. Although I would very much like to see the "neat trick".

Comment: Please sir, you can't leave me with a cliffhanger like this.

Comment: Sorry to leave you hanging, took a while to write everything up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, about the weird numbers: $v_1$ has crazy coordinates so that it can be a unit-vector.  Note that if we multiply $v_1$ by $\sqrt{13}$, we end up with $(-2,0,-3)$.

Let's start by finding **one** solution to the equation, and then characterize the rest.  In order for the equation $v_1 \times v_3 = v_2$ to make sense, $v_2$ needs to be perpendicular to both $v_1$ and $v_3$. We already know that it's perpendicular to $v_1$, but we need to be careful choosing $v_3$.  We also need to make sure that $v_3$ is not parallel to $v_1$.

A nice way to make sure that $v_3$ satisfies all these requirements is to find a $v_3$ that is perpendicular to both $v_1$ and $v_2$,  a systematic way to find such a vector is to calculate the cross-product $v_1 \times v_2$.  We could also make this computation easier by writing
$$
v_1 \times v_2 = [\frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}(-2,0,-3)] \times (0,1,0) = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{13}} [(-2,0,-3) \times (0,1,0)].
$$
We could also find a perpendicular vector without the cross product.  Note that $v$ will only be perpendicular to $v_2$ if the second coordinate is zero, which means that we're looking for a vector perpendicular to $v_1$ that has a zero in the middle.  This turns out to be pretty easy by trial and error.

Let's suppose, however, that we go with the cross-product. We end up with
$$
v = \frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}(3,0,-2).
$$
Based on our earlier discussion, we can be confident that $v$ has the right direction for our $v_3$, that is, $v_1 \times v$ will definitely be parallel to $v_2$.  However, we have to check that things match up exactly:
$$
v_1 \times v = [\frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}(-2,0,-3)] \times [\frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}(3,0,-2)] = (0,-1,0).
$$
So our $v$ is **almost** right except that $v_1 \times v$ points in the opposite direction (it does have the right length though!) So, $v_3 = -v$ will solve the equation.

Now what if we want all of the solutions?  Let's consider what happens if we plug in $v_3 + w$ for some $w$ instead.  We find that
$$
v_1 \times (v_3 + w) = v_1 \times v_3 + v_1 \times w = v_2 + v_1 \times w.
$$
So, $v_3 + w$ works exactly when $v_1 \times w = 0$.  This happens exactly when $w$ is parallel to $v_1$.

We have all of the solutions now: a vector will solve the equation if and only if it has the form
$$
v = \frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}(-3,0,2) + t v_1
$$
where $t$ can be any real number.

Comment: To skip a step, we could have noted that for a unit-vector $v_3$ orthogonal to $v_1$, the equation $v_1 \times v_3 = v_2$ tells us that the triple $(v_1,v_3,v_2)$ defines a right-handed orthonormal basis.  So, the correct order in the dot product would be $v_2 \times v_1 = v_3$ (which matches with our eventual $v_3 = -v_1 \times v_2$).

Answer (score 1):

Consider
\begin{align*}
\vec{v}_1 \times \vec{v}_3&=\vec{v}_2\\
\vec{v}_2 \times (\vec{v}_1 \times \vec{v}_3)&=\vec{v}_2 \times \vec{v}_2\\
(\vec{v}_2 \cdot \vec{v}_3)\vec{v}_1 - (\vec{v}_2 \cdot \vec{v}_1)\vec{v}_3 & =\vec{0}\\
(\vec{v}_2 \cdot \vec{v}_3)\vec{v}_1 - \vec{0} & =\vec{0} && (\because \vec{v}_1 \perp \vec{v}_2)
\end{align*}
Since $\vec{v}_1 \neq \vec{0}$, so we want $\vec{v}_2 \cdot \vec{v}_3=0$. If $\vec{v}_3=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$, then we can say $\vec{v}_3=\begin{bmatrix}a\\0\\c\end{bmatrix}$.

If $\vec{v}_3$ was to be orthogonal to $\vec{v}_1$ as well, then you have the extra condition $2a+3c=0$. In which case $\vec{v}_3=a\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-\frac{2}{3}\end{bmatrix}$.